# Excluding commons-collections 3.2 from maven-bundle-plugin

Tags: java, maven, security, maven-plugin

Currently my project is using the maven-bundle-plugin 5.1.9 version. Unfortunately we are receiving a vulnerability alert due to the commons-collections 3.2. I'd like to request your kind advice on how it might be possible to exclude this dependency from the plugin or to get it overridden by a newer version.

Following the articule described in [Maven Plugin Exclude Dependency](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/maven-plugin-exclude-dependency/?amp=1)
I've tried by creating an additional module with the intention of using it for substituting the problematic version and then add it to the dependencies section of the maven-bundle-plugin but still the same version is coming.

Thank you and I look forward to hearing from you. Kind regards

Adding the POM: `

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.tree.1987.factory</groupId>
    <artifactId>factory-tree-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0.jiffy-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../factory-tree-project</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>com.tree.factory</groupId>
<artifactId>factory-access-control</artifactId>
<name>Tree Factory Control</name>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Import-Package><![CDATA[
                     !org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler,
                     com.google.common.base,
                     org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extensions.annotation,
                     org.springframework.data.mapping,
                     org.springframework.util,
                     !com.querydsl.apt,
                     !com.mysema.codegen,
                     *
                     ]]>
                     </Import-Package>
                     <Embed-Dependency>
                        spring-data-commons;scope=runtime,
                        spring-data-mongodb;scope=runtime,
                        xmlprojector
                     </Embed-Dependency>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.encoder</groupId>
        <artifactId>encoder</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```

`

Comment: Probably a good idea to post the pom

Comment: Thanks g00se, I have posted it already